# while inserting data into synapse table data type automatically converting into Text from Varchar

Tags: python, azure, azure-synapse

I am trying to insert the data from csv into the synapse table using the python code but when the code is trying to create table it is automatically converting the string type into text

below is the code for connecting the database and creating or inserting the data into the table

```
params=parse.quote_plus("connection string")

engine=sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" %params,echo=True,connect_args={'automcommit':True})


wrt_df.to_sql(tbl_name,con=engine,if_exist="append",schema=db_name,index=false)
```

input i am giving through the excel file

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are talking about SQL pool here . The text data type is not supported by Synapse , not sure how you are seeing this text .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-data-types .

[image]

Comment: I am using the azure synapse server by using the SSMS and i am only giving the data type as varchar but while creating the table it automatically treat the data type as text not sure why is there any way to dynamically change this

Comment: Can you share the table structure which you see on the Synapse side ?

Comment: i am not using the table from synapse side i am inputting the column through excel while creating the table in the database